# Optimize 2D numpy array creation loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have the following code, which I'd like to optimize. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to gain speed or vectorize anything.

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
import numpy as np

def _compute_matrix_a(points, dw, dl, coefficient):
    """
    """
    coefficient = coefficient.reshape(points, order='F')

    extradl = coefficient[:,0] * 3
    extradw = coefficient[0] * 3

    #Build diagonals
    diagonal_a = []
    diagonal_b = []
    diagonal_c = []
    diagonal_d = []
    diagonal_e = []

    for idx, (k, i) in enumerate(product(range(points[1]), range(points[0]))):
        if k == 0:
            continue
        if k <= 1:
            pass
        elif k < points[1] - 1:
            a = 1 / (4 * dl**2) * (coefficient[i][k-1] - coefficient[i][k+1])\
                + coefficient[i][k] / dl**2
            diagonal_a.append(a)
        else:
            a = coefficient[i][k-1] / (dl + extradl[i])**2\
                + coefficient[i][k] / (dl**2 / 2 + extradl[i]**2 / 2)
            diagonal_a.append(a)

        if k == 0 or (k == 1 and i == 0):
            pass
        elif i == 0:
            b = 0
            diagonal_b.append(b)
        elif i < points[0] - 1:
            b = 1 / (4 * dw**2) * (coefficient[i-1][k] - coefficient[i+1][k]) \
                + coefficient[i][k] * (1 / dw**2 - 1 / (2 * i * dw**2))
            diagonal_b.append(b)
        else:
            b = coefficient[i-1][k] / (dw + extradw[k]) ** 2 \
                + coefficient[i][k] / (dw**2 / 2 + extradw[k]**2 / 2) \
                - coefficient[i][k] / (i * dw * (dw + extradw[k]))
            diagonal_b.append(b)

        if k == 0:
            pass
        elif i == 0:
            if k < points[1] - 1:
                c = - 4 * coefficient[i][k] / dw**2\
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / dl**2
            else:
                c = - 4 * coefficient[i][k] / dw**2\
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / (dl**2 / 2 + extradl[i]**2 / 2)
            diagonal_c.append(c)
        elif i < points[0] - 1:
            if k < points[1] - 1:
                c = - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / dl**2 \
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / dw**2
            else:
                c = - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / dw**2 \
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / (dl**2 / 2 + extradl[i]**2 / 2)
            diagonal_c.append(c)
        else:
            if k < points[1] - 1:
                c = - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / (dw**2 / 2 + extradw[k]**2 / 2) \
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / dl**2
            else:
                c = - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / (dw**2 / 2 + extradw[k]**2 / 2) \
                    - 2 * coefficient[i][k] / (dl**2 / 2 + extradl[i]**2 / 2)
            diagonal_c.append(c)

        if k == 0 or (k == points[1] - 1 and i == points[0] - 1):
            pass
        elif i == 0:
            d = 4 * coefficient[i][k] / dw**2
            diagonal_d.append(d)
        elif i == points[0] - 1:
            d = 0
            diagonal_d.append(d)
        else:
            d = 1 / (4 * dw ** 2) * (coefficient[i+1][k] - coefficient[i-1][k]) \
                + coefficient[i][k] * (1 / dw**2 + 1 / (2 * i * dw**2))
            diagonal_d.append(d)

        if k == 0 or k == points[1] - 1:
            pass
        else:
            e = 1 / (4 * dl**2) * (coefficient[i][k+1] - coefficient[i][k-1])\
                + coefficient[i][k] / dl**2
            diagonal_e.append(e)

    diagonals = [diagonal_a, diagonal_b, diagonal_c, diagonal_d, diagonal_e]
    mat_a = diags(diagonals, [-points[0], -1, 0, 1, points[0]]).toarray()

    return mat_a
    
mesh_points = (20, 50)
coefficients = np.random.rand(mesh_points[0], mesh_points[1])
dwidth = 100.
dlength = 100.
mymatrix = _compute_matrix_a(mesh_points, dwidth, dlength, coefficients)
```

I can't seem to find a way around my two loops (itertool product) to create the matrix.

I tried using np.roll:

```
# This gets the k-1
coefficients_km1 = np.roll(coefficients, 1, axis=0)
# This gets the i-1
coefficients_im1 = np.roll(coefficients, 1, axis=1)
# This gets the k+1
coefficients_kp1 = np.roll(coefficients, -1, axis=0)
# This gets the i+1
coefficients_ip1 = np.roll(coefficients, -1, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't convert the idea fully and got stuck in creating the array.

I'm open to any suggestion to optimize this function.

Comment: can you add the definition for `diags`?

Comment: Ah my bad, it is indeed missing. diags is the function from scipy.sparse: from scipy.sparse import diags